# css equal border around image on all browsers

Tags: css

I'm trying to put a solid border around an image but the spacing around the image varies in IE and other browsers and isn't a consistant on all 4 sides.

```
 <div style="float:right; border:1px solid #666666; padding: 2px;2px;2px;2px;">
 <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="mining"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysterious padding/margin appears after image in strict mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405009/mysterious-padding-margin-appears-after-image-in-strict-mode)

Answer (score 1):

Just images being .. images. Adding `display: block;` to the `img` will solve your issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/BnB4D/2/

By the way that's not how you declare multiple values (the padding), you should use `padding: 2px;` or `padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;` but `2px;2px;2px;2px;` actually takes just the first value and ends after the first `;`