# Image not taking the whole height of a div - changing the doctype fixes it

Tags: html, image, css, height

Using *HTML5* and *CSS3* I would like to have an image which uses the full height of its containing `div`. After removing most of my code I am left with this minimal fragment to represent the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div style="overflow: hidden; border-radius: 15px; background-color: aqua;"><img style="width: 100%;" src="img/napkin.jpeg"></div>
```

The fragment produces the following result:

[image]

At the very bottom there is a light blue stripe I would like to get rid of (I gave it that color on purpose in order to be visible). Any idea how to achieve that?

EDIT:
I've got the idea about the default display of images. However, one thing still bothers me. Commenting out `<!DOCTYPE html>` fixes the issue. Any idea why?

Comment: did you tried `height: 100%` along with `width: 100%`?

Comment: @SaeedJassani, Yes, I did. I've tried also with `height: auto;` It's not working. :(

Comment: Try `display: block`. It is probably because the image is inline and has some extra spacing from `line-height` not being 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Comment: @JonathanLam, What do you know... It worked. You should add this as an answer. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @scopchanov Glad to hear it! I would have if JoshMcMillan hadn't beat me to posting it as an answer =)

Comment: @JonathanLam, Usually I try to do my research, but this is one I did missed.

Comment: @JonathanLam, I still apreciate it. Besides, I find this solution more suitable than the accepted answer of the quoted question.

Comment: @JonathanLam, I've made an addition to my question. The issue is fixed, however I always try to go to the bottom of the things and if you could explain that I would be very grateful.

Comment: @scopchanov The addition is interesting. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405009/mysterious-padding-margin-appears-after-image-in-strict-mode) is another question that references the doctype issue (although none of the answers address it). Doctype is used to state what the browser is expecting; perhaps there are some additional styles in the HTML5 doctype that cause it? I'm not sure.

Comment: @JonathanLam, "Default styles in _HTML5_" definitely makes sense as a cause for the problem / fix. Please, add this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `display: block` on your `<img />` element. By default `img` tags are `display: inline;`, which includes a margin on the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the help, Josh! That works like a charm.